# Vue renderiza un componente dos veces

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

necesito ayuda... Cuando inicio sesión, voy a una lista de items y selecciono editar alguno, el app hace un $router.push a la vista de editar, el problemas es que renderiza dicho componente dos veces, me di cuenta de esto colocando un console.log() en el mounted().. Sin embargo si me devuelvo a la lista items, recargo la página y vuelvo a dar clic en editar el item entonces renderiza la pagina de editar correctamente, solo una vez.

Este es el código asociado:

```js
//listItemsView script
editItem(item) { 
  this.$router.push({ name: 'editPolicy', params:{policyTest: item}})
},

//editItemView script
export default {
  props:{
      policyTest:{
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      }
   mounted(){
      console.log(this.policyTest);
      console.log('entra');  
   },
 }
 
 //router script
 {
    path: '/editPolicy/', 
    name: 'editPolicy',
    component: () => import('../views/policies/editPolicy.vue'),
    props: true,
    meta:{requireAuth:true}
  }
  
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  if(user !== null){
    user.getIdTokenResult(true)
        .then(function ({
          claims
        }) {
          if (to.name === 'NewClient' && !claims.permissions.includes('Agregar Cliente')) {
            next({name: 'notFoundPage'});
          }else{
            //En este caso se ejecuta este next()
            next()
          }
        })
    } else {
      if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireAuth)) {
        next({name: 'SignIn'});
      } else { 
        next()
      }
  }
})
```

```html
//html
<td class="text-left">
   <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">fas fa-edit</v-icon>
</td>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Diego. Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es el español, así que debo pedirte que por favor traduzcas tu pregunta -incluyendo el título-. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente sea por que el mounted del componente esta dentro de los props, segun el código que muestras, imagino que cada vez que se monta el componenete se ejecuta el código, pero también cada vez que se pinta la prop.